# Get an enum field from a struct: cannot move out of borrowed content

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm new to Rust and trying to wrap my head around the ownership/borrowing concept. Now I have reduced my code to this minimal code sample that gives a compile error.

```
pub struct Display {
    color: Color,
}

pub enum Color {
    Blue         = 0x1,
    Red          = 0x4,
}

impl Display {
    fn get_color_value(&self) -> u16 {
        self.color as u16
    }
}
```

> ```
> src/display.rs:12:9: 12:13 error: cannot move out of borrowed content
> src/display.rs:12         self.color as u16
>                           ^~~~
> error: aborting due to previous error
> Could not compile.
> ```

I'm still in the *everything is copied by value* mindset, where it is perfectly legal to do `self.color` as that would get me a copy of `Color`. Apparently, I am wrong. I found some other questions about this same error on SO, but no solution to my issue.

As I understand it, the field is owned by whomever owns the `Display`. Since I only borrowed a
reference to the `Display`, I don't own it. Extracting `color` attempts to transfer ownership of
the `Color` to me, which is not possible since I don't own the `Display`. Is this correct?

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I'm still in the everything is copied by value mindset, where it is
>   perfectly legal to do self.color as that would get me a copy of Color.
>   Apparently, I am wrong. I found some other questions about this same
>   error on SO, but no solution to my issue.

Anything that can be copied in rust must be explicitly mared with a trait `Copy`. `Copy` was implicit in the past but that was changed ([rfc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/2860ed8ead4335f6d9a4ea285f041a61839dbeb4/active/0000-opt-in-v2.md)).

> As I understand it, the field is owned by whomever owns the Display.
>   Since I only borrowed a reference to the Display, I don't own it.
>   Extracting color attempts to transfer ownership of the Color to me,
>   which is not possible since I don't own the Display. Is this correct?

Yes. When you encounter this error there are three possible solutions:

- Derive the trait `Copy` for the type (if appropriate)
- Use/derive `Clone` (`self.color.clone()`)
- Return a reference

To solve this you derive `Copy` for `Color`:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub enum Color {
    Blue         = 0x1,
    Red          = 0x4,
}
```

This is the same as:

```
impl Copy for Color {}
```

Comment: we should use `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` since `Copy` has `Clone` as the supertrait (as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782836/the-trait-clone-is-is-not-implemented-when-deriving-the-trait-copy-for-enum))

Comment: @TaThanhDinh Thanks, fixed. Not sure if that was the case when I answered this question.

Comment: I just ran into this, except, the enum is defined in another crate, so no deriving anything for it from my end, what can I do?