# The "trait Clone is is not implemented" when deriving the trait Copy for Enum

Tags: enums, copy, rust

The following code:

```
#[derive(Copy)]
enum MyEnum {
    Test
}
```

Is giving me this error:
error: the trait `core::clone::Clone` is not implemented for the type `MyEnum` [E0277]

Why is that the case, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [`Copy` trait is a subtrait of `Clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), so you always need to implement `Clone` if you implement `Copy`:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum MyEnum {
    Test
}
```

This makes sense, as both `Copy` and `Clone` are ways of duplicating an existing object, but with different semantics. `Copy` can duplicate an object by just copying the bits that make up the object (like `memcpy` in C). `Clone` can be more expensive, and could involve allocating memory or duplicating system resources. Anything that can be duplicated with `Copy` can also be duplicated with `Clone`.

Comment: I remember a discussion on automatically deriving pre-requisite traits in `derive` implementations; do you know whether it's still planned or if there were issues with the approach that got it rejected?

Answer (score 8):

This happens because the trait `Copy`, depends on the trait `Clone`.
The compiler will not try to infer and implement the trait for you.
So you must explicitly implement the Clone trait as well.

Like that:

```
#[derive(Copy,Clone)]
enum MyEnum {
  Test
}
```